# Starting from existing project with semantic-release to publish package NOT starting at 1.0.0

Tags: npm, npm-publish, semantic-release

I have a private npm package that is currently published to npm. The maintainer before me did not consider automated versioning, and the version is 1.0.58.

I have installed semantic-release and a small GitHub app that can be found here: https://github.com/zeke/semantic-pull-requests

My Github Action is setup properly, because when I push to main, the process goes through and reach the publishing step. However, the tags that are created started at 1.0.0, then 1.0.1, etc.

I tried creating a tag manually on the main branch at the latest merge, that tag is v1.0.58, but when I publish again, the tag that is created is still 1.0.2, etc. As such, I get an error message that says I can't publish "over" the current version.

How do I go the 1.0.59 with a fix:... commit?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: This seems like a question for the maintainers of the `semantic-pull-requests` package.

Comment: Given that the error occurs when running "npx semantic-release" during a ci script, I strongly believe it is related to semantic-release. semantic-pull-requests does its job, it validates the commit format, which I ensured was correct, it essentially adds a check for commit prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to post solution...

It seems Semantic Pull Requests did not have a proper starting point as the initial tag was created after it was linked to the repository. Uninstalling Semantic Pull Requests, adding the latest tag (corresponding to current version of published npm package) manually and reinstalling Semantic Pull Requests caused to process to go through flawlessly with semantic-release.